# Why doesn't this regular expression generate a match?

Tags: regex, grep

I have the following configuration file:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth            substack        system-auth
auth            include         postlogin
account         sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account         include         system-auth
password        include         system-auth
session         include         system-auth
session         include         postlogin
session         optional        pam_xauth.so
```

The spaces appear to be tabs.  Turning on list (:set list) in vim shows me:

```
#%PAM-1.0$
auth^I^Isufficient^Ipam_rootok.so$
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.$
#auth^I^Isufficient^Ipam_wheel.so trust use_uid$
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.$
#auth^I^Irequired^Ipam_wheel.so use_uid$
auth^I^Isubstack^Isystem-auth$
auth^I^Iinclude^I^Ipostlogin$
account^I^Isufficient^Ipam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet$
account^I^Iinclude^I^Isystem-auth$
password^Iinclude^I^Isystem-auth$
session^I^Iinclude^I^Isystem-auth$
session^I^Iinclude^I^Ipostlogin$
session^I^Ioptional^Ipam_xauth.so$
```

I want to match on the line:

```
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

Matching on the entire line does not work.  I'm not sure why...guessing it is something to do with spaces tabs:

```
grep "#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid" /etc/pam.d/su
```

(Returns no match)

So, I thought it would be worth trying to match by saying:

```
grep "#auth\s+required\s+pam_wheel.so\s+use_uid" /etc/pam.d/su
```

I'm reading this regular expression as "#auth" followed by at least one or more tabs/spaces followed by "required" followed by at least one or more tabs/spaces followed by "pam_wheel.so" etc...

However, this doesn't match either.  I'm not sure whats going wrong here. What am I missing?

Comment: `grep` regular expressions don't support the `\s` escape sequence. If you're using GNU grep, use the `-P` option to use PCRE regexpts.

Comment: You should also escape the full stop in "pam_wheel.so" - > "pam_wheel\.so"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[[:blank:]]` in your regex which matches a space or a tab:

```
grep '#auth[[:blank:]]*required[[:blank:]]*pam_wheel\.so[[:blank:]]*use_uid' /etc/pam.d/su

#auth       required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

Comment: Remember to escape the fullstop just incase.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Extended Regular Expressions

By default, grep uses the basic regular expression (BRE) engine. If you want the extended regular expression engine (ERE) with its support for character-class shortcuts like `\s`, then you need to run `egrep` or `grep -E` instead. For example:

```
$ egrep "#auth\s+required\s+pam_wheel\.so\s+use_uid" /etc/pam.d/su
#auth       required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

Alternatively, you can use a grep with the Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE) library built in by using `grep -P` or `pcregrep`. However, this is not supported on all platforms.

### References

- `man 7 re_format` for more details on the differences between BRE and ERE.
- `man 3 pcre` for information about the PCRE library and syntax.

Comment: Thank you both.  However, its not matching for either posted expression either. 
I feel this may be some invisible character, encoding, or some other 
characteristic I've overlooked.  If i were to copy the line from the file, 
paste it into an echo command, and send it through grep the expression matches:
$ echo "#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid" | \
egrep "#auth\s+required\s+pam_wheel\.so\s+use_uid"
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
However, when I feed the entire file into grep the exact same expression fails.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I didn't realize I needed to use extended expressions, and was not escaping the .